# Keep getting linker error on adding constructor to my struct

Tags: c++, struct, linker, linker-errors

So this file compiles just fine. If I decide to add a constructor to my default object, I get linker errors.

```
#ifndef VERTEX_FORMATS_H_
#define VERTEX_FORMATS_H_

#include "../utilities/float3.h" (this file does not have other includes within it)
#include "../utilities/float2.h" (this file does not have other includes within it)

struct VERTEX_PARTICLES
{
    float3 v3fPosition;     //has a default constructor that set its own values to zero
    float3 v3fVelocity;     //has a default constructor that set its own values to zero
    float3 v3fAcceleration; //has a default constructor that set its own values to zero
    float fCurLife;
    float fEndLife;
    float fCurScale;
    float fStartScale;
    float fMidScale;
    float fEndScale;
    unsigned int uiColor; 

    VERTEX_PARTICLES( void );
};


VERTEX_PARTICLES::VERTEX_PARTICLES( void ) :
    fCurLife( 0.0f ), fEndLife( 0.0f ),
    fCurScale( 0.0f ), fStartScale( 0.0f ),
    fMidScale( 0.0f ), fEndScale( 0.0f ),
    uiColor( 0U ) { }

#endif
```

The file compiles just fine if I remove the constructor, but having a constructor gives me linker errors:

> VERTEX_PARTICLES::VERTEX_PARTICLES(void)"(??0VERTEX_PARTICLES@@QAE@XZ) already defined in Game.obj

I have a guess that it's complaining that elsewhere I'm adding this file more than once? But I didn't think it'd be an issue since I #defined my object, and also it wasn't giving me issues without a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The:

```
#ifndef VERTEX_FORMATS_H_
#define VERTEX_FORMATS_H_
```

Does not protect against multiple "implementations" of the constructor `VERTEX_PARTICLES::VERTEX_PARTICLES( void )`:

For example, if you have 2 cpp files, both using `#include "vertex_formats.h"`

Both will include the header, and you will have 2 implementations of the constructor, therefore it will be compiled twice and the linker finding 2 same named definitions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define it in the header unless it is inline. The way you defined it, it will get picked up everytime the file is included.

I should build like so:

```
struct VERTEX_PARTICLES
{
    float3 v3fPosition;     //has a default constructor that set its own values to zero
    float3 v3fVelocity;     //has a default constructor that set its own values to zero
    float3 v3fAcceleration; //has a default constructor that set its own values to zero
    float fCurLife;
    float fEndLife;
    float fCurScale;
    float fStartScale;
    float fMidScale;
    float fEndScale;
    unsigned int uiColor; 

    VERTEX_PARTICLES( void ) :
        fCurLife( 0.0f ), fEndLife( 0.0f ),
        fCurScale( 0.0f ), fStartScale( 0.0f ),
        fMidScale( 0.0f ), fEndScale( 0.0f ),
        uiColor( 0U ) { }
};
```

Comment: ok wow i can't believe i made such a silly error.... i guess thats what i get for coding while tired haha. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!